# XSLT - How do I hold information to be added together without modifying a variable?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to write an XSLT document that will transform information I've previously pulled from an MEI XML document into an SVG graph. The problem I'm running into is that there are sometimes multiple elements within a specific value that need to be converted before they are added together. My first impulse is to use a series of if-statements and add the results together, but XSLT variable can't be modified.

Here is a snippet of my XML code:

```
<song>
   <verb>
      <word>Close</word>
      <connotation>negative</connotation>
       <duration>4</duration>
    </verb>
       <verb>
      <word>Hide</word>
      <connotation>negative</connotation>
      <duration>4</duration>
   </verb>
   <verb>
      <word>Bar</word>
      <connotation>negative</connotation>
      <duration>4</duration>
   </verb>
 </song>
```

Here is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="/">


    <svg height="100%" width="100%">
        <g transform="translate(50,220)">

            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="{count(//verb) * 21}" y2="0" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
            <line x1="0" y1="-200" x2="0" y2="200" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>

            <line x1="-4" x2="4" y1="20" y2="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
            <text x="-12" y="25">2</text>

            <line x1="-4" x2="4" y1="40" y2="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
            <text x="-12" y="45">4</text>

            <line x1="-4" x2="4" y1="60" y2="60" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
            <text x="-12" y="65">6</text>

            <line x1="-4" x2="4" y1="80" y2="80" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
            <text x="-12" y="85">8</text>

            <line x1="-4" x2="4" y1="100" y2="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
            <text x="-21" y="105">10</text>

            <line x1="-4" x2="4" y1="120" y2="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
            <text x="-21" y="125">12</text>

            <line x1="-4" x2="4" y1="140" y2="140" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
            <text x="-21" y="145">14</text>

            <line x1="-4" x2="4" y1="160" y2="160" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
            <text x="-21" y="165">16</text>

            <line x1="-4" x2="4" y1="180" y2="180" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
            <text x="-21" y="185">18</text>

            <line x1="-4" x2="4" y1="200" y2="200" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
            <text x="-21" y="205">20</text>

            <line x1="-4" x2="4" y1="-20" y2="-20" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
            <text x="-12" y="-15">2</text>

            <line x1="-4" x2="4" y1="-40" y2="-40" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
            <text x="-12" y="-35">4</text>

            <line x1="-4" x2="4" y1="-60" y2="-60" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
            <text x="-12" y="-55">6</text>

            <line x1="-4" x2="4" y1="-80" y2="-80" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
            <text x="-12" y="-75">8</text>

            <line x1="-4" x2="4" y1="-100" y2="-100" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
            <text x="-21" y="-95">10</text>

            <line x1="-4" x2="4" y1="-120" y2="-120" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
            <text x="-21" y="-115">12</text>

            <line x1="-4" x2="4" y1="-140" y2="-140" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
            <text x="-21" y="-135">14</text>

            <line x1="-4" x2="4" y1="-160" y2="-160" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
            <text x="-21" y="-155">16</text>

            <line x1="-4" x2="4" y1="-180" y2="-180" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
            <text x="-21" y="-175">18</text>

            <line x1="-4" x2="4" y1="-200" y2="-200" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
            <text x="-21" y="-195">20</text>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="//verb"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="verb">
    <xsl:variable name="verbpos" select="position() - 1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="xposition" select="$verbpos * $barInterval"/>
    <xsl:variable name="barHeight" select="duration * 10"/><!-- remember to multiply by 10 later -->



  <!-- if test each duration within verbs
      if = to a specific note, assign actualValue


      <xsl:if test="duration = 4">
   <xsl:variable name="acutalValue" select="1"/>
    </xsl:if>-->


    <xsl:if test="connotation = 'positive'">
        <rect x="{$xposition + $barShift}" y="-{$barHeight}" stroke="black" stroke-width=".5"
            fill="#e2727b" width="{$barWidth}" height="{$barHeight}" class="{lower-case(word)}"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="connotation = 'neutral'">
        <rect x="{$xposition + $barShift}" y="-{$barHeight div 2}" stroke="black"
            stroke-width=".5" fill="#bcdce5" width="{$barWidth}" height="{$barHeight}"
            class="{lower-case(word)}"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="connotation = 'negative'">
        <rect x="{$xposition + $barShift}" y="0" stroke="black" stroke-width=".5" fill="#5c305c"
            width="{$barWidth}" height="{$barHeight}" class="{lower-case(word)}"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

What kind of data structure should I use for this conversion? Or is there an easier way? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you post desired XML result from example snippet XML? Your description and code is not immediately intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

A variable doesn't necessarily hold a single value, in fact you can have an entire document in a variable, and you can even declare temporary variables inside a variable declaration that are only within the scope of the declaration.

For example:

```
<xsl:variable name="myVar">
  <xsl:variable name="temp">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="childNodes"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$parameter = 'value'">
      <xsl:text>myVar contents</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:text>There are </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="count($temp//*)"/>
      <xsl:text> elements in temp</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

The point is, you can have all your logic inside the variable declaration itself, including any conditionals. Whatever a template can output, a variable can store. Sorry I haven't offered specific help, but I don't clearly understand your requirements, but I hope this technique will point you in the right direction.